# VB Excel ignore dates before today

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create pop up notifications in Excel on Due Dates.
I have found the following VB code which works perfectly fine , but I would also like to ignore the previous dates, before yesterday.

Is that possible?

I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
 If DateDue < Date Then
NotificationMsg = ""
End If
```

That's the original code

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim DateDueCol As Range
Dim DateDue As Range
Dim NotificationMsg As String

Set DateDueCol = Range("B2:B500") 'the range of cells that contain your due dates
For Each DateDue In DateDueCol

'Change H2 to the cell for bring forward reminder days in your data
If DateDue <> "" And Date >= DateDue - Range("O2") Then
'Change the offset value to pick up the invoice number column in your data
    NotificationMsg = NotificationMsg & " " & DateDue.Offset(0, 0)
End If

Next DateDue
If NotificationMsg = "" Then
MsgBox "You do not need to complete any SHOPPING, today."
Else: MsgBox "The followinging Shopping need to be completed today: " & NotificationMsg
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, what does `- Range("O2") ` supposed to do?

Comment: Use a variant variable: `Dim ddv As Variant: ddv = DateDue.Value` : `If IsDate(ddv) Then` : `If ddv >= Date - 1 Then`?

Comment: Davesexcel : the o2 is a cell indicating a number. -range(o2) is today minus the number of days indicated by the number written in cell o2

Comment: @VBasic2008 . Not sure I understand. If I write this code then the dates before today will be ignored ? My question is: what do I put after Then so as to make the code ignore previous dates?